# How can I calculate the sample size in this multivariate problem?

Tags: correlation, sample-size, networks

I have two data sets containing scores of a test applied to two groups of people: A control group (neurotypical individuals) and a group of people with a specific neurological condition. The aim is to decide, by mean-comparison test, if there is strong evidence suggesting the test can indeed identify when an individual has the condition.

The data provide scores on 10 different processes (variables) related to specific brain regions. Let's take a nonempty set of the data (more than one individual). The scores are run into a correlation analysis which, given a proper threshold, yields a set of links among some of the variables (i.e. a graph -in the sense of graph theory- is computed). Then, some formulas (which provide information on topological properties of the graph that we are interested in) are calculated (e.g. connectivity of the graph, degree of the nodes, etc). For the results of these calculations, the means-comparison test is aimed (for more details, check the book *Fundamentals of Brain Network Analysis* by A. Fornito, A. Zalesky & E. Bullmore).

Here I have two questions that I don't know how to tackle:

1. Given that I have no general information about the statistics (i.e. standard deviation, mean, whether the distribution is normal, etc.), how can I decide how many graphs I have to compute from both groups to run a mean-comparison test for a confidence interval?
2. Supposing $n$ is the answer to the first question, how should I calculate the number of individuals (i.e. the random sample size) to generate each of the graphs?

I would appreciate any ideas or suggestions into the literature, or even any corrections should there be any. Thanks!